# Rigify Store Selected Handles somehwere

Tags: rigify

I'm new here. I'm using blender 2.8a on Pc.
I have a rigify rig (not mine), often I need to select specific "handles" of the rig (for handles I mean the circle or squares or boxes that allow you to move the bones, see picture attached).
Is there a way to save this "selection" somewhere in a blender? so next time that I need them I don't need to re-select one by one, and is quite a time consuming, any suggestion?
thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a New Bone group (adding it to the existing ones), or move them into a single layer.

[image]

Comment: Cheeers, many thanks. I don't know how to do that, but now I have a valid starting point, I'll go to the manual now to see how to assign the bone group to a layer :)

Comment: And I did it :) it works, thanks Josh for your help :)

Comment: @LucaC Please mark the answer as accepted **✓**, to keep the site nice and tidy :).